# How to use couch2elastic4sync

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb

I have used couchdb 1.6.1 and elastic 1.7.3
I want elasticsearch couchdb integration, so I found [couch2elastics4sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couch2elastic4sync) but I don't know npm.
I installed couch2elastic4sync and ran it, but it's not working...

How do I use it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I success..

edit couch2elastic4sync

root@dev:/usr/bin#vim couch2elastic4sync

var config = require('rc')('couch2elastic4sync', {
  addRaw: false,
  rawField: 'raw',
  endOnCatchup: false,
  removeMeta: true,
  urlTemplate: false,
  load: {
    swallowErrors: false
  },
  concurrency: 5,
  checkpointSize: 20,
  retry: {
    times: 10,
    interval: 200
  },
  ***elasticsearch: 'http://localhost:9200/couchdb/ektorp',
  database: 'http://localhost:5984/ektorp'***

})

root@dev:/usr/bin#couch2elastic4sync

work...